# Regex rewrite rule for filename with dash

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got a filename like `jquery.form.min.3.51.0-2014.06.20.js` and want to change the following my rewrite rule to remove the dots, the dash and the digits.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The rewrite rule does it jobs on filenames like `scripts.min.4.4.2.js` which is forwarded to `scripts.min.js`. But for the filename at the top, with the dash inside between the digits, the rule won't work.

My regex knowledge is too limited for this case. Could anybody give me a hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.[\d-]+\.(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(\D+)[\d.-]+(js|css|png|jpg|gif)$ $1$2 [L]
```